# Using a list with string elements be used as the name of the files to create in a for loop

Tags: python, list, csv, file, pycharm

I have a days list in which each element is named after the days of the week. ["monday","tuesday", "wednesday", etc.]. But I get an error from PyCharm stating this:

"This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of functions parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations."

```
    if choice == 1:
    day = input("Which day of the week would you like to create a file for?")

    days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

    for i in range(days):
        if day == days[i]:
            with open(",day", day, "_tasks.csv", "w") as day_csv:
                writer = csv.writer(day_csv)
                writer.writerows(day)
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would be grateful.

Comment: "But I get an error from PyCharm stating this:" What you quoted is not an error message. It's an explanation of something that PyCharm tries to do to help look for problems in your code.

Comment: That said, try looking more closely at the line of code it's highlighting. In your own words, what do you expect `range(days)` to do? What do you expect `for i in range(days):` to do? What do you think is the purpose of `range`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably `for i in range(days)` isn't right. The `range()` function expects a number, not a array. Try:

```py
for i in range(len(days)):
        if day == days[i]:
            with open(",day", day, "_tasks.csv", "w") as day_csv:
                writer = csv.writer(day_csv)
                writer.writerows(day)
```

---

However, using a loop here doesn't really make sense to me considering you're already having the day being entered in by the user. My guess is that you're just trying to verify if the date is correct, in which case I would suggest this:

```py
if choice == 1:
    day = input("Which day of the week would you like to create a file for?")
    day = day.lower()    # Make day lowercase 
    
    days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
    
    if day in days:
        with open(",day", day, "_tasks.csv", "w") as day_csv:
            writer = csv.writer(day_csv)
            writer.writerows(day)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know my coding is week. I am still new haha. Thank you for your help.